# Laravel 5.4 default value in role_id

Tags: laravel-5.4

in fact I am new to laravel, and I have a problem with my application.
I have a table USERS (id, login, password, role_id, firstname, lastname, email)
I would like to record and the role_id always has a default value of 1, because at my place in ROLES table (id, role) the admin has ID 1 and the member has the value 2.
I would like that the modification is in the controller or model not on the migrations.
thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you set a default value for field on DB level?

Answer (score 1):

When you saved user and you have data add role_id key in data.
Fore example
Controller

```
   public function (Request $request) {
       $data = $request->all();
       $data['role_id'] = 1;

       if (User::create($data)) {
           // some message for successfully created
           return redirect('some-route');
       }

       // some message for failed to save user
       return redirect()->back();
   }
```

Comment: If my answer help you make as acepted